# How to create admob interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

It's not like this before. I watched a lot of videos to learn how to do it, but none of them tell me that part. What should I do with the manifest file? How do I add ads successfully?
I'm new to this. Please help me.
[image]

```
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-1843350439017364~2248748181"
        android:value="[ca-app-pub-1843350439017364~2248748181]" />
```

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase, in your assistant you can find adMob

Comment: create an app in admob... ull see your id.

Comment: @PaoloColombo i add manifest.xml code, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add your id without [ ]

like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

you can use this version of Admob library if you want to work like videos that you watch:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

Comment: im using this version implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'. THANK YOU, YOU ARE MY HERO @Abdomns